# Android dagger hilt

Tags: android, dependencies, code-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have one class NavigationController which requires an activity instance all of my fragment are hosted through these activity.

```
class NavigationController constructor(private val activity: MainActivity) {
    
    fun navigateToAuth() {
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container,WelcomeFrag())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
}
```

And here is my NavigationModule

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)

@Module
object NavigationModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesNavigationModule(activity: MainActivity): NavigationController {
        return NavigationController(activity)
    }
}
```

But i'm getting Error as MainActivity cannot be provided requires @Inject or @Provides
I know dagger doesnt know how to create MainActivity as it doesnt have constructor i cannot inject it

So how could i get activity and pass it to my NavigationController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your `NavigationModule` depends on the `Activity`, you're installing it in the wrong `component`. You should be using `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)`.
2. Within the `Activity` scope (===`ActivityComponent`) Hilt can provide an instance of an `Activity` as a dependency. It cannot provide an instance of your exact `MainActivity`. **It's hard to judge just from your code samples** if this can fulfill your needs, but you might get away with simply:

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
object NavigationModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesNavigationModule(activity: Activity): NavigationController {
        return NavigationController(activity)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. it worked i just changed the parameter to Activity and casted to MainActivity as my application just has one main Activity